# Notation for every other row in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

This maybe a bit of a silly question but what is the correct notation for every other row/column in a matrix? So essentially I want to mathematically denote row 2,4,6,8,10...etc or columns 1,3,5,7...etc.

Comment: You could say $R_{2k}, C_{2k-1}$?

Comment: in terms of this notation then k would be equal to half the length of the column or row, right?

Comment: For $A_{m\times n}, R_{2k}, C_{2p-1},k\in\{1,2,...,\lfloor m/2\rfloor\},p\in\{1,2,...,\lceil n/2\rceil\}$

Comment: that makes sense to me, thank you